# problemas de Json com Vue.js

Tags: json, vue.js

observe abaixo;

Minha pagina

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My books</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="container" id="app">
    <div class="row">
        <h1>Book</h1>
    </div>

<div class="row">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>id</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Nome</th>
            </tr>   
        </thead>    
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>teste boook<td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>


</div>

<script src="node_modules/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/vue-resource/dist/vue-resource.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Meu arquivo Json

```
{
    "id":1,
    "title":"feira da rua",
    "value":50,
    "descricao":"dcjndkjscnkjdsnckjdnsckjndskjcn"
}
```

Meu arquivo Javascript

```
var app = new Vue({
    el:'#app',
    data:{
        banco:[]

    },
    methods:{

    },
    ready:function(){
        var self = this;
            self.$http.get('dataServer.json').then(function(response){
            console.log(response);          
        });

    }


});
```

Estrutura do meu projeto;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por que será que não está aparecendo o objeto no consoles do meu navegador?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

===========================================================

Depois da modificação sugerida gerou um erro

ficou assim;

```
created:function(){
        var self = this;
            self.$http.get('dataServer.json').then(function(response){
            console.log(response);          
        });

    }
```

dá uma olhada no erro;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Vue não tem nenhum método nativo `ready`, o ["ciclo de vida"](https://br.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html) de uma instância é:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Deves usar o `created` que é chamado quando a instância é criada, pois não precisas esperar pelo `mounted` que é chamado quando o componente é inserido no DOM.

Comment: eu fiz uma alteração na minha postagem, e fiz as alterações que você sugeriu fazer, mas gerou um erro no consoles do navegador.

Comment: @wladyband se vais mudando a pergunta a minha vai ficando desatualizada... Que servidor tens? PHP, Node? ou estás a correr sem servidor?

Comment: não estou usando servidor web, esse é o problema? precisa está rodando num servidor web?

Comment: @wladyband sim, exato. Coloca no github ou noutro site e usa de lá. Senão podes usar um `import response from '../tua/pasta/dataServer'` e no `created` usas `this.response = response`, por enquanto. Assim pelo menos tens o código no sitio certo para o dia em que o ficheiro estiver online.

Comment: foi isso mesmo, muito obrigado.